# Typescript - How to add type definition to React classical component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Passing multiple component types to `Component` seems to ignore the `second` type.

```
class Car extends Component<State, Dispatch> {
  ...
  // State works, Dispatch gets ignored
}
```

Dispatch gets ignored when it is the **second** argument.

If I reverse the order, `Dispatch` code will work, `State` will be broken (be ignored).

The `<Types>` are interfaces. Is this the correct way to pass multiple Types to `Component`?

Comment: What do mean by "works" and "ignored"? How are you expecting to use those types in `Car`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a close view of the type definition file `index.d.ts` of `React.Component` (command + click to open)

> node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts

You will find out that the `React Component` do accept the second one, but it's not been used as **Props**, it's **State** instead.

```
class Component<P, S> {
  ...
```

If you want to bind dispatch to your Component, **bind with props**.

You can find the specific implementation as below:

Refer to the document of redux: [typing-the-connect-higher-order-component](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component)

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface RootState {
}
const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
})
const mapDispatch = {
}
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
  backgroundColor: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
)

export default connector(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the part I wasn't understanding. The fact that the first argument is for Props, and the second is state. All I was seeing everywhere is `<P, S>`

Answer (score 1):

The types inside component are for Props (first one) and State (seconds one). It seems like you are trying to use them for something else:

```
class Component<P, S> {
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L408 for reference.

If you are trying to use redux with react and typescript , check this out: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/